# Request.headers missing or undefined

Tags: node.js, express, request, request-headers, x-forwarded-for

Hopefully somebody will find this a relatively simple answer, but it is beyond me at the moment.  I have a Node.js/Express setup.  I am simply trying to retrieve the client IP address upon each request to the site.  My code is as follows:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

...

// Start server...
var webServer = app.listen(process.env.PORT || port, function(request, response) { 
  console.log(" Received request for " + new Date()); 

  var _FORWARD_IP = request.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
  console.log('_FORWARD_IP (CLIENT IP ADDRESS): ' + _FORWARD_IP);       
});
```

However this throws the following error:

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined"

Therefore it seems there are no headers in the 'request' object within the 'app.listen' command.  I am unsure how to resolve, this is the initial instance of dealing with something like this.  If anybody knows an answer or a workaround it is greatly appreciated.  I thank you in advance.

Regards

Comment: That is not (exactly) how you set-up an Express server. Sure, you have to listen to a port, but the callback you give it is not supposed to receive any request. Have a look at the [Hello World](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) example from official docs, it is pretty straightforward. You can also look at the [.listen() method](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen) to see how to use it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Sorry I didn't include the 'port' number in my code.  Otherwise my code is essentially identical to that given in the 'Hello World' example, except for the 'arrow function' usage.  Why do you write "the callback you give it is not supposed to receive any request"...?  The callback function I have does specify both 'request' and 'response'...can you explain what is it that prevents a the callback from receiving the 'request'...?  Thanks again

Comment: Upon reading your reply again...are you stating that there should NOT be any callback in the 'app.listen' as I have it?  As in the 'Hello World' example where the callback is 'blank'...?

Comment: Thank you for your posting, the information you gave was helpful.  My understanding has certainly been improved.  Regards.

Comment: Looking back at my comment, I realize it was not as informative as it could be. The answer you validated was much better, and glad you could sort it out!

Comment: No problem, I appreciate your input...thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.listen()` just starts the server, telling it to *listen* for requests. There is no request at that point in your code.

This sounds like a job for some [custom middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const _FORWARD_IP = req.get('x-forwarded-for');
  console.log('_FORWARD_IP (CLIENT IP ADDRESS):', _FORWARD_IP);
  next();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  // This callback executes when the server is ready to accept connections
  console.info(`Express server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will change my 'app.listen' as you (and Gaëtan Boyals) have indicated.  I will also insert the 'app.use' middleware as well.  I will try to get this fixed later today or tomorrow.  I thank you very much for the information, much appreciated.

Comment: I have made the adjustments to my 'app.listen' and inserted the 'middleware'.  Although I have no errors, I am still unable to get the client IP address (logs as 'undefined').  This might be caused by settings in IISNODE acting as a reverse proxy on my server...need to do more research.  I thank both of you for useful and insightful responses.  Regards.

Comment: I was able to get this working.  As previously suspected I was having a problem with a setting in IISNODE however that is resolved.  I thank you again for the informative posting.  Regards.